Probability of a collision in function that maps each prime $p$ to the range $[p]\times[p]$.
I am looking for an approximation of
\begin{align*}
P(x)=1-\prod_{i=1}^{\pi(x)}\frac{p_i^2-i+1}{p_i^2},
\end{align*}
where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime and $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.
This is the probability of a collision where I have a function that (we assume uniformly randomly) maps each prime $p\leq x$ to the range $[p]\times[p]$. This is similar to the birthday problem, but I don't think it is easily adaptable to this situation.
